# vue-router in html file and how to connect routes to other files

Tags: vue.js, handlebars.js, hapi.js, vue-router

I'm using hapi and handlebars with vue and vue-router. This means I have to use script tags for vue and vue-router instead of using npm packages. So this means my vue and vue-router codes are not in a js file, but in a html file. So if I want to connect a html file to a route specified by vue-router, I can't use the import command. How can I do it then?

Comment: You're going to have to do a better job at describing the problem. AFAIK, you don't connect HTML files to routes, you assign components. The components can have templates. Where exactly are you having trouble?

Comment: When you're using vue and vue-router as npm packages, the way to assign components to routes, is to import them like "import foo from ./bar/foo.vue". But: 1) When you're using vue and vue-router as scripts in a html file, you can't work with .vue files and you have to use html files. 2) the import command is provided by nodejs and is not part of javascript. So you can't use it as in a script in a html file.

Comment: You'll need to register your components, either globally or locally. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html. You will not be able to use single-file components